# Github says "Waiting for status to be reported" for a valid existing job

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a PR where I want a certain check to be completed before I can merge to master. Here is the job
https://github.com/hhimanshu/typescript-serverless-api-vercel/actions/runs/763599870

Now, in the PR, its status is not reported. Here is the PR

https://github.com/hhimanshu/typescript-serverless-api-vercel/pull/4

I looked at the similar question asked in the past at https://github.community/t/expected-waiting-for-status-to-be-reported/18001, however, the reason for this issue in that question was

> In most cases, this is because you had deleted the job or changed the job (renamed it) from the workflows, but did not to update the branch rules.

But in my case, the job name is the same, and the job is **not** deleted either, so the solution does not apply.

My branch protected rule has this job as "Required"
[image]

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Realistically you'll have to message GitHub support, we can't tell you much from out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I needed was a way to update `status` by using Github REST API.

```
# We must set the commit status manually
      # Reference: https://github.com/bahmutov/eleventy-example/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L27
      - name: Staging Tests ✅
        if: ${{ success() }}
        # set the merge commit status check
        # using GitHub REST API
        # see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/statuses/${{ github.sha }} \
          --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
          --header 'content-type: application/json' \
          --data '{
            "context": "Staging Tests",
            "state": "success",
            "description": "Staging tests passed",
            "target_url": "https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}"
          }'
      - name: Staging Tests 
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        # set the merge commit status check
        # using GitHub REST API
        # see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/statuses/${{ github.sha }} \
          --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
          --header 'content-type: application/json' \
          --data '{
            "context": "Staging Tests",
            "state": "failure",
            "description": "Staging tests failed",
            "target_url": "https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}"
          }'
```

After that, the PR shows the link in the checks. The link is https://github.com/hhimanshu/typescript-serverless-api-vercel/pull/4

I learned about that from https://github.com/bahmutov/eleventy-example/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L27 while working through my way using https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/develop-preview-test/

After this, I see status being updated as expected, with a link that takes me to the job

[image]

I hope this helps others as well

Comment: Are we supposed to add that code somewhere? In Circle CI?